# thread profiling and monitoring

Tags: linux, thread, profiling

how can I get lock time values specifically of the threads of any process? in linux..
I was using the command /proc/pid/stat but I am unable to determine which values are of lock time.

Answer (score 0):

`/proc/[pid]/stat` and `/proc/[pid[/statm` are about processes. So locks at thread level can't be seen there. Detailed description can be find [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/procfs.5.html):

Some time ago I was looking at [this](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/introducing-linux-splat/) tool. Hope you find it useful. :)

Comment: thank you.. but I am unable to open the tool link.

Comment: @I192100MayraAhmad should work now... sorry for messing. I'll remove this comment later this week :)

Comment: splat tool isn't working for me as my operating system is ubuntu 20.04. I think this is not compatible with ubuntu distributions.